# How to request a package for Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, ux

I want to see [Webcamoid](https://github.com/hipersayanX/webcamoid) in my Ubuntu. What is the process to request the package?

There are instructions how to build the stuff manually at https://github.com/hipersayanX/webcamoid/wiki/Build-and-install-the-Debian-package but that is far from good user experience.

I would be able to maintain a package if the whole packaging and testing process (including API compatibility testing) could be made from web.

Comment: hipersayanX needs to provide a personal archive for it. Oh and someone named Panda Jim tried but the package got deleted ( https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/webcamoid-deletedppa/+build/7017122 )

Comment: @Rinzwind can this PPA be made and tested by someone else online?